# Successive .NET Parallel For's - Blocking after each

Tags: .net, parallel-processing

I have several Parallel.For operations in succession.

I am currently examining each Parallel.For's return value `ParallelLoopResult` and sleeping for 20 milliseconds until the `IsCompleted` member is set to true.

```
Dim plr as ParallelLoopResult 

plr = Parallel.For(...)

while not plr.IsCompleted
  Thread.Sleep(20)
end while

plr = Parallel.For(...)

while not plr.IsCompleted
  Thread.Sleep(20)
end while

.
.
.
```

How can I add a kernel level block (i.e. WaitHandle) in place of the loop and Thread.Sleep?  Is there a completion event that Parallel.For triggers?  Does Parallel.For provide for such a mechanism?

Answer (score 4):

The `Parallel.For` will complete all code that it was called for. The `IsCompleted` only returns `false` then the loop was interrupted.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopresult.aspx:

> If IsCompleted returns true, then the loop ran to completion, such that all iterations of the loop were executed. If IsCompleted returns false and LowestBreakIteration returns null, a call to Stop was used to end the loop prematurely. If IsCompleted returns false and LowestBreakIteration returns a non-null integral value, Break was used to end the loop prematurely.

Comment: True, but doesn't answer my question of how to wait until the loop completes using a kernel level construct.

Comment: But, there is nothing to wait on. It think what you're asking is how you can sleep the thread until some even signals that `IsCompleted` is changed. The problem is that `IsCompleted` will never change after `Parallel.For` has completed.

Comment: If I create a WaitHandle, how could I signal that wait handle when the Parallel.For completes?

Comment: AFAIK a Parallel.For does not block until all tasks complete.  I need to block until the loop completes, preferably using a kernel level mechansim.

Comment: The `Parallel.For` will always complete before it returns. I think what you're looking for is `Task.Factory.StartNew()`.

Comment: Yes, it does block until the loop completes.

Answer (score 1):

You cant get `WaitHandle` for `Parallel.For()` and you dont need to - call is synchronous (all iterations will be completed after call is finished). If you need to execute loop itself on other thread, not only iterations, you must wrap it in `Task` or `Thread`, and that objects will provide you wait handles. But if you are goint to wait for results on the same thread as you call `Parallel.For()` (as in your sample code), it doesn't make any sense.