# How to run a Parallel.For loop for a condition

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, parallel-processing, conditional-statements

I'm new to Parallel Programming in C# and am finding it difficult to implement in real time. Here is my query:

```
public string[] SequentialFun(int count)
{
    string[] results = new string[count];
    for(int run = 0; run < count; run++)
    {
        while(true)
        {
           //Generate a Random Number (62 bit) and store it in variable 'randNum'
           if(randNum is prime)
           {
               results[run] = randNum.ToString();
               break;
           }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

1. How to apply parallel programming for the above function to increase the speed?
2. Tell me how to run a `Parallel.For` loop until a condition? 
   Please explain and help me with detailed explanation.

Comment: Parallel isnt always synonymous with "increased speed".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396256/parallel-for-fail-c

Comment: as @SimonWhitehead said, parallel programming should be used when taking into account the cpu's architecture. It doesn't necessarily translate to faster code execution.

Comment: This is an embarrassingly parallel problem (assuming the `is prime` check doesn't use shared data structures). It's obviously advantageous to use parallelism, unless you're running on a CPU older than 8 years.

Comment: @Douglas Of course.. just pointing out a mistake in the OP's statement.

Comment: @Ravi: That issue applies to dynamic structures, such as `List<T>`. The array is this example is allocated before the loop, so there is no risk of race conditions.

Comment: @Douglas I pointed to that question to kill 2 birds with one stone!
1) Show Usage of Parallel.For
2) Point out problems in using Parallel.For

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your sequential loop:

```
for (int run = 0; run < count; run++)
{
    // ...
}
```

...with a parallel one:

```
Parallel.For(0, count, run =>
{
    // ...
});
```

Comment: yeah its working. But this statement  results[run] = randNum.ToString(); is always updating a single string only.

Comment: Ensure that the `randNum` variable is declared *inside* the parallel loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Parallel.For` method and place your logic inside the anonymous delegate:

```
Parallel.For(0, count, (i, results) =>
    {
       while(true)
       {
          //Generate a Random Number (62 bit) and store it in variable 'randNum'
          if(randNum is prime)
          {
              results[run] = randNum.ToString();
              break;
          }
       }
    }
);
```

Remember though that using `Parallel.For` does not mean that the efficiency of your code's execution will be improved x-times as it depends on the amount of processor cores.

Comment: I'm getting an error: Cannot convert lamba expression to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.PrallelOptions' because its not a delegate type.